# Tooltip in table header

Tags: css, header, tooltip, fixed

I have a scrollable table with fixed header and columns, and tooltips in the header.  There is also a rowspan in the header.  I have tried for a long time now to get the tooltips in the header rows to show over top of the header cells in the following rows.  I can not seem to find a solution even after reading everything I can find on stacking contexts and z-index, including the W3C specs.

CSS:

```
.gradebooktable {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px
}

table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-width: 0;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

td {
  position:relative;
  padding: 3px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}

th {
  position:relative;
  z-index:20; 
  background: #999;
}

th.pinned {
  position: relative; 
  z-index: 40;     
  background: #ccc;
}

td.pinned {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 30; 
  background: #eee; 
}

.tooltip{
  position:relative;
}

.tooltiptext{
  display:none;
  position:absolute; 
  z-index:10;
  border:1px;
  background-color:#eee;
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:1px;
  border-color:blue;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding:3px;
  color:blue; 
  top:20px; 
  left:20px;
}

.tooltip:hover span.tooltiptext{
  display:block;
}
```

HTML:

```
<BODY>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<SCRIPT>
$( function() {
$('#gradebooktable').scroll( function() {
      var translate = "translate(0," + this.scrollTop + "px)";
      $("table thead th:not(.pinned)").css('transform', translate);

      translate = "translate(" + this.scrollLeft + "px,0)";
      $("table tbody .pinned").css('transform', translate);

      translate = "translate(" + this.scrollLeft + "px," + this.scrollTop + "px)";
      $("table thead th.pinned").css('transform', translate);
    }
);  
});
</SCRIPT>
  <div id="gradebooktable" class="gradebooktable">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="pinned" rowspan=3>Col 0</th>
          <th class="pinned" rowspan=3>Col 1</th>
          <th class="tooltip">Col 2A
               <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip for header cell</span></th>
          <th class="tooltip">Col 3A
               <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip for header cell</span></th>
          <th class="tooltip">Col 4A
               <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip for header cell</span></th>
          <th class="tooltip">Col 5A
               <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip for header cell</span></th>
          <th class="tooltip">Col 6A
               <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip for header cell</span></th>
          <th class="tooltip">Col 7A
               <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip for header cell</span></th>
          <th class="tooltip">Col 8A
               <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip for header cell</span></th>
          <th class="tooltip">Col 9A
               <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip for header cell</span></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Col 2B</th>
          <th>Col 3B</th>
          <th>Col 4B</th>
          <th>Col 5B</th>
          <th>Col 6B</th>
          <th>Col 7B</th>
          <th>Col 8B</th>
          <th>Col 9B</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="pinned">First Cell</td>
          <td class="pinned">Second Cell</td>
          <td class="tooltip">Another Cell
                  <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip for body cell</span></td>
          <td class="tooltip">Another Cell
                  <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip for body cell</span></td>
          <td class="tooltip">Another Cell
                  <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip for body cell</span></td>
          <td class="tooltip">Another Cell
                  <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip for body cell</span></td>
          <td class="tooltip">Another Cell
                  <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip for body cell</span></td>
          <td class="tooltip">Another Cell
                  <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip for body cell</span></td>
          <td class="tooltip">Another Cell
                  <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip for body cell</span></td>
          <td class="tooltip">Another Cell
                  <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip for body cell</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="pinned">First Cell</td>
          <td class="pinned">Second Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="pinned">First Cell</td>
          <td class="pinned">Second Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="pinned">First Cell</td>
          <td class="pinned">Second Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="pinned">First Cell</td>
          <td class="pinned">Second Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="pinned">First Cell</td>
          <td class="pinned">Second Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="pinned">First Cell</td>
          <td class="pinned">Second Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
          <td>Another Cell</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
</BODY>
```

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/k42myms3/5/

The goal is to get the tooltips in the top row of the spanned header rows to show on top of the cells on the bottom row of the spanned header rows. I can find ways to get the tooltips to show, for example by removing position:absolute from the .tooltiptext css, but not without either causing positioning problems or breaking the table cells scrolling behind the fixed headers and columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, fixed it: https://jsfiddle.net/k42myms3/10/

Code added:

```
th.tooltip{
  position:relative;
  z-index: 35; 
}
```

... and a few other things.